# Android RS232 through headphone jack?

Tags: android, serial-port

We are looking to send serial commands thorough the headphone jack on an Android device.  I've found some tutorials that explain how to receive communication through the headphone jack but I haven't found anything that explains if it's possible to send a command though the jack.

What we are attempting to do is use the jack to send serial commands to an Arduino to turn on various pins on the arduino.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Just **for fun**, I guess, because a **tethered** communication is **nearly useless**. Bear in mind that an HC-05 **BlueTooth** module costs about **5 USD** in China. And they usually **ship for free**.

Comment: Thanks.. yes actually we do have a teathered use case for it, and we also have a way to wirelessly transmit the signal as well.. I'm just trying to figure out if it's possible to send the data out as the first step.

Comment: Yes, it is. Imagine you are sending out a modulated signal (like a radio signal or a power supply network). There's a signal over a carrier. OR, in a much simplified version, you can send out TONES then some PLLs (Phase Locked Loop) react to specific frequencies (well, Arduino can act as an advanced PLL). 1 PLL is enough, since you want to react to 1s only, and the rest is 0s.